# Access VBA attachments

Tags: vba, image, ms-access, attachment

I'm trying to add an image into an Image Frame in Access. I have a table called "App_Parameters" in which I have inserted the attachment link of the image, also wrote in the description field next to it "LogoImage".

Now, in a report form, I have the Image Frame, and this is the code that I wrote in the "On Open" event:

```vb
Private Sub Report_Open(Cancel As Integer)

    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
   
    Set db = CurrentDb
   
    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("App_Parameters")
   
    If Not rs.EOF Then 
        rs.MoveLast
        rs.MoveFirst
        rs.FindFirst ("Description = 'LogoImage'")
        Me.LogoImg.PictureData = rs!ImageLogo   
    End If

End Sub
```

My problem: this is not getting any values "rs!ImageLogo"

Answer (score 0):

I would use rs.Fields("ImageLogo").Value as below. Please check the field name "ImageLogo" matches the name of the attachment field in your "App_Parameters" table :)

```
Private Sub Report_Open(Cancel As Integer)
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
    
    Set db = CurrentDb
    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("App_Parameters")
    
    If Not rs.EOF Then
        rs.MoveLast
        rs.MoveFirst
        rs.FindFirst "Description = 'LogoImage'"
        
        If Not rs.NoMatch Then
            ' Assuming "ImageLogo" is the name of the attachment field
            Me.LogoImg.PictureData = rs.Fields("ImageLogo").Value
        End If
    End If
    
    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    Set db = Nothing
End Sub
```